# how to add selected rows into NSMutableArray in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add selected rows in to my array.when I am adding second selected row into myArray the first object is replace with second and every time I am getting only one object in myArray.Here is my table didSelectAtIndexPath: method code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)        
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [myArray addObject:[Array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"myArray %@",myArray);   
    }
}
```

can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is caused by this line:

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You are allocating this array each time when user clicks a cell.

Allocate it in your `viewDidLoad`.

or Add a condition before allocating like:

```
if(myArray == nil)
{
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Perfect :) That's the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   self.Array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self.myArray  addObject:[self.Array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Comment: what new this adds to the existing answer?